# How to insert ending tag before an element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

We have editors who can write blog posts for our site and in that editor they can click a button that creates an element `<div class="subscribe-call-to-action">Call to action will come here</div>`.

Everything is wrapped in a `<div class="container-fluid post_description_container">` where inside I have a `<div class="col-md-6 post_description">` and I am trying to insert a full width element into the page dynamically which means I would need to close that `<col-md-6 post_description>`.

I tried to use `.insertBefore()` and `.before()` but non of these work.

How can I close the `<div class="col-md-6">` and then append the full width element and then restart the `<div class="col-md-6 post_description">`?

Comment: You can use `prepend()` instead of `insertBefore` or `before()`

Comment: @SuperUser it does not add the closing div tag

Comment: You can use it like `$('.post_description').prepend('</div>').html('new html')`

Comment: It's probably just an expression but... jQuery operates on the DOM, where the idea of manipulating start and end tags separately does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up using was pure css for the dynamically added container. Here it is

All credit goes to here: https://coderwall.com/p/hkgamw/creating-full-width-100-container-inside-fixed-width-container

```
.subscribe-call-to-action {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method to wrap element using an HTML tag.

```
$element.wrap('<div clas="classnames"></div>')
```